# Is it acceptable to use a casual and jokey style in posts?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I created this post because of the author's comment on
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3262082/622310)

I found this post particularly difficult to read, and wrote a comment about the comedy content to say so. For me, the casual and jokey style effectively hides any useful information.

Given that
it is considered inappropriate to write
stuff like "hi" and "thanks",
and to duplicate a tag in a question's subject line,
I find it hard to defend such bulky and frivolous content.

Am I right to vote down submissions like this?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, a lot of software IS actually a joke.  CR/LF is only one such frivolity that the audience has to put up with once they have bought their software development ticket.

Comment: Tabs/spaces is another long-runnig joke.  There a whole languages that are a joke, like brainfuck, malbolge and PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to see a really good question saying "Thank in advance", would you downvote it just because of the unnecessary salutation? Or would you see through the fluff for the good content that lies within and edit it to be more appropriate?

It's the same case here. Is the answer so irredeemably bad that it is of no worth or value beyond the joking? If yes, by all means downvote it. If not, make the needful edit, upvote if you wish, and move on. That's your privilege as a user with edit rights.

As for the answer in question, I read through the whole thing, and while I did feel there was a lot of off topic rambling, there weren't any major felonies that would warrant a downvote.

This actually reminds me of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949453/4909087)...

Answer (score 14):

I think as long as it gets the point across, the style of a post isn't that important, and writing in a  casual or humorous style isn't inherently a problem.

If the style becomes an impediment to understanding the post, then it's a problem, but whether or not that has happened seems like a judgement call to me. Of course your vote is your decision, but personally, I would downvote a post if I thought its casual/humorous style obscured its content enough to make it "not useful," but not simply because it had that style. I know we hate fun, but I think most people would agree that it's easy to find posts that have worse problems than trying to be funny.

Based on your opinion that the answer was difficult to read and that any useful information it might have had been hidden, it seems reasonable for you to downvote it.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I right to vote down submissions like this?

You can downvote posts for any reason you like; we can't stop you.

Does it make the site *better* to downvote such posts? It depends entirely on the post. Does the humor interfere with the content of the post? Does it make it difficult to parse the factual information out of it?

If the post is perfectly clear and provides good information which answers the OP's question, I see no benefits for the site by downvoting it just because it contains a (lame) joke.

Answer (score 5):

Dude, that answer was, like, totally awesome and, like, deserves an upvote? You could, like, take a chill pill or something?

Writing in an entertaining, idiosyncratic, dialectal, or otherwise marked style can be, like, y'know, funny sometimes? And, like, everyone needs to laugh or smile sometimes?

Comment: For some reason, I'm considering flagging this as not an answer? (Not really?)

Comment: Its, like, not an answer at all though, eh? It's, like, just a bunch of, like, questions, eh? @Don't

Comment: Perhaps you meant this to be humorous, but *You could, like, take a chill pill or something?* is not really constructive.

Answer (score 3):

We've had lighthearted content in answers before, but we've historically only kept it if it added value to the answer overall, or at least didn't *detract*.

You can feel free to downvote these sorts of answers if you like, but if you do have the energy or time to invest in it, you could take a swipe at editing it to remove the noise from it.